# how to open/read a feature file with .pth extension

Tags: python, file, feature-extraction

I have a file with .pth extension. It actually is a features/model file. Please let me know how can I read/open the complete file

Comment: Is it a PyTorch file? You need to read it via PyTorch or some other libraries that can handle that file format

Comment: @gimix yes it is a pytorch file. I tried so many ways. Nothing worked so far. I tried to open it in colab but it only shows a bit of weights and output not the complete file and coloumns.

Comment: Check the [PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/saveloadrun_tutorial.html). Basically a PTH files can contain only weights, or a full model instead so you need to know how it was saved